# getProperty() method in java.util not able to recognize keys value variables in ${.} inside springboot's application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a springboot application where the application.properties look like this -

```
keyA=valueA
keyB=valueB
keyC=${keyA}
```

So I know that using the `@Value` annotation, I can correctly get the value of `keyC` as "valueA". However, my program is currently taking the use of a read only file where the `getProperty()` method returns the value of `keyC` as "${keyA}" instead of "valueA".

**Sample Code**

*read-only*

```
public String getPropertyValue(String prop){
FileReader reader = new FileReader("app.properties");
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(reader);
System.out.println(p.getProperty(prop));
}
```

```
getPropertyValue("keyC");
```

**Output**

```
${keyA}
```

**I will not be able to modify the read only file.** I want to know if there's any suitable alternative to add a variable like `${keyA}` in application.properties so that it can be recognized by the `getPropertyValue` method. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to post-process the Properties yourself, replacing all values of which key name matches the pattern "^${(.*)}$" by the corresponding value of the key being the group 1 of the pattern. (Be careful to possible buggy cross-references of values in the .properties... that may lead to infinite loop...)